# Different evince on Ubuntu software GUI _22.04

Tags: apt, snap, pdf, evince, 22.04

I am seeing 2 Evince document viewers in the Ubuntu software GUI. One is the deb version and the other is the snap version. Both are of different size and version. My first question is are they the same? Because it says the dev is Gnome for the deb version and the other is Ken VanDine for the snap version.

Second question is regarding the version. I'm currently running the deb version as it shows installed on the Ubuntu software GUI, however, the version differs. The Ubuntu software GUI show the latest version available is 42.1, however, my is 42.0. I've did the usually `apt-get update apt-get upgrade`, however, don't see any updates or upgrades for Evince.

Reason for the questions is because I'm facing the Evince unable to remember last read page and cannot bookmark issues (which I've posted and reported bug). Hence, is hoping the 42.1 is an actual update that'd fix the problems. And not needing to use the snap version for a working document viewer.

Kindly advise

Comment: Please try and report back here in an answer - it is perfectly fine to ask a question and provide your own answer here. Edit the title of your question to better reflect the question.

Answer (score 0):

Tested the snap version which has the exact same problem of not remembering last read page and cannot bookmark issues. In summary, the snap version has the same problems but takes up more space and has additional permissions configuration which aren't required from the deb version. I've attached a screenshot from the GUI after the snap version with the permissions config.

[image]